# multiple slideshow on one page works bad

Tags: javascript, slideshow

a beginner here : ) 
I know it's been asked before but I couldn't find a solution yet. I have two automatic slideshows running one beneath the other on one page. they both work, but work awfully bad, the timing is not as set and it's not looping as it should be. but - if I keep only one slideshow in the page, it works perfectly fine. I'm struggling with it for hours already.

this is my html:

```
        <div class= "gallry">
        <ul id="slides" dir="rtl" onclick="nextSlide">

            <li class="slide showing"> <img id="firstImg" src=".img.jpg"> </li>
            <li class="slide"> <img src=".img1.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slide"><img src=".img2.jpg"></li>
        </ul>  
    </div>





    <div class="gallery">
        <ul id="slides2" dir="rtl">


            <li class="slidetwo showing"> <img id="firstImg2" src=".img3.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slidetwo"><img src=".img4.jpg"></li>
            <li class="slidetwo"><img src=".img5.jpg"></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

this is my css

```
#slides {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#slides2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}


.slidetwo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}


img {
    max-height: 95vh;
    max-width: calc(100vw - 80px);
}

.showing {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

and this is my javascript:

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000);

function nextSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}


var slides2 = document.querySelectorAll('#slides2 .slidetwo');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlideTwo,1000);

function nextSlideTwo() {
    slides2[currentSlide].className = 'slidetwo';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides2.length;
    slides2[currentSlide].className = 'slidetwo showing';
}
```

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing I see is that you're trying to reuse the same global variables for both slideshows. What's happening is that when both of those calls in the `setInterval()` are running, they're addressing the same variables, which would result in the images being displayed out of order, timing issues, and other similar things.

What I'd recommend trying would be trying to separate the variables out, so that `nextSlide()` and `nextSlideTwo()` are addressing and updating different things as they run. For example:

```
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000);

function nextSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}


var slides2 = document.querySelectorAll('#slides2 .slidetwo');
var currentSlide2 = 0;
var slideInterval2 = setInterval(nextSlideTwo,1000);

function nextSlideTwo() {
    slides2[currentSlide2].className = 'slidetwo';
    currentSlide2 = (currentSlide2+1)%slides2.length;
    slides2[currentSlide2].className = 'slidetwo showing';
}
```

Will throw this in a fiddle shortly to see how it runs and if any additional tweaks are needed.

Comment: Putting that into jsfiddle with the HTML and CSS you provided showed that it worked, but it also hid the UI at the top after I ran it, so I wasn't able to save and/or share.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works perfect now! 
I really appreciate your help : )